# Efficient approach to populate the temp table

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11gr2

```
Default_accounts
========================
p_type        varchar2
t_type        varchar2
A         varchar2
B         varchar2
C             varchar2
D             varchar2
=========================
```

`p_type` and `t_type` is the primary key of the table

```
p_type  t_type  A   B  C  D
============================
apple    sell   Y   N  N  Y
banana   buy    N   N  N  Y
orange   sell   Y   N  N  N
mango    buy    Y   Y  N  Y
papaya   buy    Y   N  N  Y
apple    buy    Y   N  N  Y
banana   sell   Y   Y  Y  Y
============================


 Accounts_Exceptions
=============================
acc_excep_id          number    --sequence (Primary key)
p_type                varchar2
t_type                varchar2
excep_attribute       varchar2  --contains column of default_accounts like A,B,C,D
priority              number
excep_base_sql        varchar2
excep_value           varchar2
===============================
```

`Unique constraint` :p_type,t_type,excep_attribute and priority 
`foreign_key`       :p_type and t_type  from `Default_accounts`

```
  acc_excep_id   p_type    t_type  excep_attribute priority  excep_base_sql   excep_value
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     1           apple    buy       A              1         --some--         XYZ
     2           apple    buy       A              2         --some--         PQR
     3           banana   sell      B              1         --some--         GHT
     4           banana   sell      B              2         --some--         GFF
     5           orange   sell      C              1         --some--         DSA    
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

`excep_base_sql`: it contain a sql query like `select 1 from alloc where alloc_id =:alloc;` --its a sample query but it always contain bind vairable :alloc

1. Now my requirement is that i got a cursor having which contain records of `alloc_id ,p_type,t_type`
2. I put the records in  a temporary table having structure as below:

   ```
    alloc_id p_type  t_type  A   B    C   D
   ---------------------------------------------
    11       apple   buy    
    22       apple   sell
    33       mango   buy
    12       mango   buy
    13       mango   buy
    24       banana  buy
    54       orange  sell
   ```

   ---

   3.But as you see ,i need to populate A,B,C and D value  in bulk ,temp table can contain around `millions of record`.

   4.For populating the value i need to check the account_exceptions table first for any exception .
   For example: i fetched `11  apple   buy` from the temp table  and see the exception table ,In exception table find records having `p_type` as `apple` and t
   `t_type` as `buy` order by priority in ascending order .

   5.So, records with `acc_excep_id` :`1,2`  are fetched , i fetch first record  and run the `excep_base_sql` with `alloc_id` 11 ,if row is returned then i ll update
   the `excep_attribute` A with `XYZ` in temp table and then skip  the second record having priority 2 ,because the record with priority one satisfy .

   6.If no entry of `apple buy` is present in execptions table ,then i need to populate the temp table with default_accounts table ,so this value is `Y`.

   7.So ,if no exception satisy then default value is picked from `default_accounts`.

   8.In short i need to populate the value of `A B C D` in table `temp`.

   9.I need a way to efficiently populate the data into temp table  for value `A B C D` .

Can anyone help me with this approach

Comment: @Justin Cave:Can you suggest a better approach to populate the table

Comment: Is this something you need to do regularly or just once ?

Comment: @A.B.Cade: Not regular ,once in a month,my idea is to store the value in a temp table once and then return the cursor of this temp table where it get stored into a table xyz .So after that all the fetch is from xyz table

Comment: all:I don't know the reason of closing this question ,someone vote for closing this question without any reason(comments).

Comment: The given reason for a closing is Not A Real Question.  Somebody thinks your question is hard to understand.  And who can blame them?

Comment: @APC:The protocol is to ask what they din't get ,rather than just closing this .I think i have tried my level best to elaborate my requirement .nyways if all want i will delete this question

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to recommend two things.

1)  An insert as select or create table as select is always the most efficient when doing a bulk insert.

2)  It "sounds" like you are trying to convert rows into columns.   I would recommend Oracle's pivot feature.  The pivot feature is described here:  [Oracle Base Pivot](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1.php)